# Want to get an AWS lambda error to client console

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get an error message passed from Lambda to show up on my client. Basically I call an API Gateway endpoint from my client, which executes a lambda. There is a certain condition in this function and if this condition fails I want to send a specific message to my client. This is what I currently have.

A library:

```js
export function failure(body) {
    return buildResponse(500, body);
}

function buildResponse(statusCode, body) {
    return {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
        },
        body: body
    };
}
```

and the actual function:

```js
export async function main(event, context) {

    const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const saleCount = await getSaleCount();

    if (count >= 25) {
        // This is the error i'm referring to
        return failure({ status: false, error: 'My error' });
    }

    const params = {
        TableName: process.env.salesTable,
        Item: {
            foo: bar
        }
    };

    try {
        await dynamoDbLib.call('put', params);
        return success(params.Item);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return failure({ status: false });
    }
}

async function getSaleCount(foo) {
    // do stuff and return value
    return bar;
}
```

I can't seem to get the message in this error on the frontend. There is a try-catch clause and the error is definitely being picked up by the catch, but the error simply displays as

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:59)
```

Furthermore, I can actually see the message as a response on my Network tab:

```
{"status": "false", "error": "My error"}
```

It is a Lambda Proxy integration, so I've tried following the methods on this page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html
Meaning:

```js
// This returns me a 502 on the frontend
throw new Error('My error');

// This also doesn't allow me to access the message
return {statusCode: 400, body: 'My error'};
```

I'm at an absolute loss now so I'd really appreciate any input. Many thanks!

Comment: This is your http client problem. What is the lib you are using? Like `fetch`, `axios`...

Comment: Hey! I'm only using the aws-sdk for this on the backend and aws-amplify on the frontend. The calls are made in a very simple manner.

`
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';

function loadPurchases(user) {
    return API.get('some name', path);
 }
`

Comment: In your `catch` block, try line `console.log(e.response.data);` - `e` is the error object

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but you're an absolute hero. e.response.data.error got me the actual error message I was looking for. Thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the e.response.data was null, because the response I was getting was not a json but a text. But in my network response I could see the message.

My solution was to add a `responseType = "text"` in the request object. After that I could see some text in the data attribute.

Allowed values for responseType are “arraybuffer”, “blob”, “document”, “json” or “text”; and it defaults to “json” if not specified.

You can read more here: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/fetch/q/platform/js#accessing-query-parameters--body-in-lambda-proxy-function